# Is there a way to run a Java Program when you don't know its name?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm making a game engine using LWJGL. The developer using it has to be able to use scripts. I decided to just make them use Java because writing an API in another language wasn't something I'm going to have the time nor experience to do. Anyways, I would have used `x.main();` to run it, but The developer tells what the script is named, and that is stored in a variable. I just thought I could run a command to do that, using a method like `exec()` in python or `eval()` in JavaScript. I couldn't find a straightforward library that has this execution functionality.

To summarize this paragraph, I need a Java Library that can use a method like JavaScript's `eval()` or python's `exec()`

Comment: Java files alone cannot be ran as scripts. They need compiled. After compilation, you could scan them and look for main methods with reflection

Comment: Use reflection to get method instance and execute it by name

Comment: @OneCricketeer this is not technically true, java files can be run with hashbang `#!` syntax, added in JEP 330.

Comment: Please provide an example of what one of these "scripts" will actually look like.  Is it a Java class?

Comment: @StephenC It looks like a unity Script. A Loop and a Start method. The code is then executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know If I understood the problem, but I have focused on part of having "script name stored as variable" which sounds to me like a method name. You can invoke method by its name using reflections

```
public class MCAlu {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        String scriptName = "sayHello";
        Method scriptMethod = MyScript.class.getMethod(scriptName);
        scriptMethod.invoke(null, null);
    }
}

class MyScript {
    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hi there!");
    }
}
```

Since class has to be known and on the classpath (unless you will load it in the runtime), class name can be as well provided as string resulting in

```
String scriptClass="MyScript";
String scriptName = "sayHello";
Method scriptMethod = Class.forName(scriptClass).getMethod(scriptName);
scriptMethod.invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

One (quite popular) tool that can help you run Java sources as scripts is [JBang](https://www.jbang.dev/). Java programs *have* to be compiled (to Java class files) to be able to run by a JVM. So, basically, JBang hides this compilation step and invokes the JVM with our compiled class.

Comment: Recent Java versions can do this directly (for single source applications)

Comment: I know its old comment but thought I would just clarify a bit here:
Java 11+ can run single source files, but dependencies is all up to you to manually handle.

JBang works with Java 8+, works with single and multi file projects and handles dependencies for you. Thats the big difference.